# Oracle - what can be done to remove Full Table Scan/Table Access Full?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlperformance

Oracle SQL which needs to be tuned:

```
SELECT mcei.mcei_sid
FROM MA_CE mc
JOIN MA_CE_EN mce
ON mc.mc_id=mce.mc_cd
JOIN MA_CE_EN_IN mcei
ON mce.mce_sid                =mcei.mce_sid
WHERE mc.active_flag          = 'Y'
AND mce.active_flag           = 'Y'
AND Mcei.Latest_Full_Run_Flag = 'Y'
AND Mcei.Engine_Type_Cg_Sid   = GE_CG_SI_FR_C_SN ('MEI_ENGTYPE','COB')
AND Mcei.Mcei_State_Cg_Sid    = GE_CG_SI_FR_C_SN ('MCEI_STATE','COMPLETED')
AND Mc.Mc_Id         = NVL(6,Mc.Mc_Id)
AND mcei.business_dt = NVL(NULL -- this is a parameter which could be NULL or a Date       
  ,
  (SELECT mcei.business_dt
  FROM MA_CE_EN e
  WHERE e.current_cob_mei_sid  =mcei.mcei_sid
  AND e.active_flag            ='Y'
  AND mcei.Latest_Full_Run_Flag='Y'
  AND e.mce_sid                =mce.mce_sid
  ));
```

Explain plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                               |     1 |    40 |   825   (2)| 00:00:10 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                        |                               |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                    |                               |   376 | 15040 |   636   (3)| 00:00:08 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                               |     1 |    14 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MA_CE                         |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | IPK_MA_CE                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | MA_CE_EN                      |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL           | MA_CE_EN_IN                   |  4817 |   122K|   632   (3)| 00:00:08 |
|*  8 |   FILTER                       |                               |       |       |            |          |
|*  9 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | MA_CE_EN                      |     1 |    11 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | IPK_MCENG                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

```
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("MCEI"."BUSINESS_DT"= (SELECT :B1 FROM "MA_CE_EN" "E" WHERE :B2='Y' AND 
              "E"."MCE_SID"=:B3 AND "E"."CURRENT_COB_MEI_SID"=:B4 AND "E"."ACTIVE_FLAG"='Y'))
   2 - access("MCE"."MCE_SID"="MCEI"."MCE_SID")
   4 - filter("MC"."ACTIVE_FLAG"='Y')
   5 - access("MC"."MC_ID"=6)
   6 - filter("MCE"."ACTIVE_FLAG"='Y' AND "MC"."MC_ID"="MCE"."MC_CD")
   7 - filter("MCEI"."LATEST_FULL_RUN_FLAG"='Y' AND 
              "MCEI"."MCEI_STATE_CG_SID"="GE_CG_SI_FR_C_SN"('MCEI_STATE','COMPLETED') AND 
              "MCEI"."ENGINE_TYPE_CG_SID"="GE_CG_SI_FR_C_SN"('MEI_ENGTYPE','COB'))
   8 - filter(:B1='Y')
   9 - filter("E"."CURRENT_COB_MEI_SID"=:B1 AND "E"."ACTIVE_FLAG"='Y')
  10 - access("E"."MCE_SID"=:B1)

---------------------------------------------------
```

**No. of rows in the 3 tables used in the query :**

```
    ma_ce - 10  
    ma_ce_en - 10   
    ma_ce_en_in - 160000
```

**(ma_ce_en_in  table is culprit. Primary key on columns MCEI_SID and MCEI_SID_SEQ. No other index on this table.)**

**Question 1** - I want to tune the query so I don't want Full Table Scan(or Table Access Full) on  ma_ce_en_in  as this is the only big table. What can be done to remove Full Table Scan from this table?

**Question 2** - The above query is present in a function, how to find how many times the function runs in a week?

Comment: I'm not very sure what is FTS?

Comment: It's full table scan OR table access full. Edited my question too.

Comment: Apparently Oracle is completely under estimating the number of rows in `ma_ce_en_in`. Are your statistics up to date?

Comment: That scalar sub-select in the `where` clause seems strange (if not useless). You are comparing the column `mcei.business_dt` to itself. Did you mean that to be a join condition instead? e.e.g `JOIN MA_CE_EN_IN mcei
ON mce.mce_sid  = mcei.mce_sid and mcei.business_dt = ???`?

Comment: Yes I have gathered the statistics and the above counts of the 3 tables are exact count.

Comment: Could you show a definition of this fuction: `GE_CG_SI_FR_C_SN` ? The full table scan probably is not a problem, but using this function can cause poor performance.

Comment: That sub-select is tested and good. It has some other conditions too which  are being evaluated. Also carefully see the table name, it is different but has similar name.
My main aim is to remove Full Table Scan from MA_CE_EN_IN table.How can I do that? Also please help me on my second question.

Comment: krokodilko - code of the function is below. But I dont think it is the problem. please take a look.

`SELECT
cg_sid
into
out_cg_sid
from
code_generic cg
where
cg_sname = p_cg_sname
and cgt_sname = p_cgt_sname
and ((active_flag = 'Y' AND P_Ignore_Active_Flag = 'N') OR P_Ignore_Active_Flag = 'Y' );
return out_cg_sid;`

Comment: Make an index then you will have seek not scan.

Comment: **Just me know what are the ways to remove Full Table Scan from that table? thanks**

Comment: @Hogan - 
`create index test on ma_ce_en_in(Latest_Full_Run_Flag,Mcei_State_Cg_Sid,Engine_Type_Cg_Sid);`
is this the best index or something else we can do?
After creating the index, 3 Nested Loops have come in the explain plan, are they ok? or should we convert them to hash join, if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments, way down below the post (instead of IN THE POST where it should be), you state that you have an index on LATEST_FULL_RUN_FLAG, MCEI_STATE_CG_SID and ENGINE_TYPE_CG_SID.

How many rows have the FLAG set to 'Y'? (You can run a simple query to find out.) If the answer is "half the rows" or even "15% of the rows", the optimizer will likely choose not to use the index. (If only 1% of the rows had the flag set to 'Y' then the index should be used.)

If that is so - are either the STATE_CG_SID or the ENGINE_TYPE_CG_SID more selective? For example, each possible value appears in no more than 1% of the rows? If so, you should put the most selective of the columns FIRST in the multi-column index; the only way the optimizer can use the index is if the value for the FIRST column in the index is very selective. Otherwise you will end up with a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 - The above query is present in a function, how to find how many times the function runs in a week?

Answer - You cannot find the no. of times a function has been executed. But you can find how many times its sql has been executed.

**a)**
To find the no. of execution, you can check AWR but it could be possible your sql is NOT  picked up by the awr.
You can execute below to get stats of all sql in awr.

```
begin
    dbms_workload_repository.modify_snapshot_settings (topnsql=>'MAXIMUM');
end;
```

**b)**
However, you may not be allowed to run the above code into prod. So the next option is to check oracle views.

1. Find the SQL_ID from its text

   select executions,v.* from v$sql v where  sql_text like '%select * from ABCtable%';--90771ja3rt3rw
2. `select executions_delta-- "Executions"
   from   dba_hist_sqlstat t, dba_hist_snapshot s
   where  t.snap_id = s.snap_id
   and    t.dbid = s.dbid
   and    t.instance_number = s.instance_number
   and sql_id='90771ja3rt3rw' 
   --  and to_char(BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2017-05-15'
   ;`